# Generate all possible combination of n-pair parentheses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, combinatorics, balanced-delimiters

**The task** is taken from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/)

> *Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.*
>
> *For example, given n = 3, a solution set is:*
>
> ```
> [
>   "((()))",
>   "(()())",
>   "(())()",
>   "()(())",
>   "()()()"
> ]
> ```

**My solution**

is based on [backtracking](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Maybe there's a better approach than that? The reason I do this task is because I want to improve my skills. So, if you got any improvement suggestions or an alternative approach - no matter how fancy it is - feel free to post it here.

```
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {string[]}
 */
var generateParenthesis = function(n) {
  const addParanthesis = (cur, open, close) => {
    if (cur.length === n * 2) {
      res.push(cur);
      return;
    }
    if (open < n) { addParanthesis(cur + '(', open + 1, close); }
    if (close < open) { addParanthesis(cur + ')', open, close + 1); }
  };
  const res = [];
  addParanthesis('', 0, 0);
  return res;
};
```

Comment: Please provide us with some insights how you got to this solution or what parts you think can be improved. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated with additional information even though I didn't had to do it in my previous questions. I always assumed CR works like code review in real life: You get code and than review it. Usually you don't have to provide the other party the information how you got to the solution.

Comment: The problem with posting code without any additional information or question, is that we don't know what you are looking for in a review. In addition, statistically, the quality of an answer correlates with that of the question :)

Comment: @thadeuszlay - Here is javascript's style guide - https://github.com/airbnb/javascript - I found it really helpful.

Comment: Other than the minor naming issues / lack of immediate clarity about how it's working, this solution is quite nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Names

The plural of *parenthesis* is *parentheses* (as used in the specification). So I think it would make more sense to call the top level function `generateParentheses`, or even `generateBalancedParentheses`.

The inner function should be `addParenthesis` (with an `e` substituted for the third `a`).

Opinions will vary on `cur` as an abbreviation for `current`. I think it's common enough to be easily recognised, although given the meaning of the value it names perhaps `prefix` would be better.

`open` and `close` read to me as verbs, although `open` could also be a count of the number of parentheses which have been opened and not closed (i.e. the surplus of `(` over `)` in `cur`). I've reverse engineered that they count, respectively, the number of `(` and `)` in `cur`. Perhaps `opened` and `closed` would be clearer, along with a comment explaining what they are.

#### Scope

Although JavaScript is very forgiving of the order of declarations, humans tend to read code in order. I would find it clearer if `res` were defined *before* `addParenthesis`, since that references it.

#### Correctness

Although the code looks correct to me, I would like to see some comments to justify *why* it's correct. Why are the `if` guards necessary and sufficient?

With these comments, you would also be able to justify a slight simplification:

```
  const addParenthesis = (prefix, opened, closed) => {
    if (closed === n) { res.push(prefix); }
    if (opened < n) { addParenthesis(prefix + '(', opened + 1, closed); }
    if (closed < opened) { addParenthesis(prefix + ')', opened, closed + 1); }
  };
```